# axios accepting a URL object in renderer process, but not in main process

Tags: javascript, axios, electron

I have a React app that runs in Electron. Throughout all of the renderer process code, I've been using axios as follows:

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

...

const { data: queryResponse, isLoading } = useQuery(
    [query, getParameters], () => {
        const url = new URL(`https://www.devel.server/${query}`);
        url.search = new URLSearchParams(getParameters);
        return axios.get(url);
    }
);
```

Now I tried to run the same code in the main process, and suddenly I'm getting exceptions:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const { odtParse } = require('./main/odt-parser.js');
const shell = require('electron').shell;
const path = require('path');
import axios from 'axios';

ipcMain.on('generate-employee-contract', (event, employeeId) => {
  const url = new URL('https://www.devel.server/employee-contract-summary');
  url.search = new URLSearchParams({ employeeId });
  axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
    const filename = odtParse('./assets/Contract.odt', response.variables, response.conditions);
    shell.openPath(path.join(__dirname, filename));
  })
});
```

This is the error I'm getting from the `axios.get()` call:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:
> The "url" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of URL

What's going on? Why does same code work in one process but not in the other? Is it using different axios instances somehow?

EDIT: as requested, the output of `console.log(url)`:

```
URL {
  href: 'https://www.devel.server/employee-contract-summary?employeeId=377',
  origin: 'https://www.devel.server',
  protocol: 'https:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'www.devel.server',
  hostname: 'www.devel.server',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/employee-contract-summary',
  search: '?employeeId=377',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams { 'employeeId' => '377' },
  hash: ''
}
```

Comment: Do a `console.log(url)`. The url is probably malformed.

Comment: @JohnYepthomi The URL is not malformed.

Comment: Please show the console.log(url) result. Comment out the axios for now.

Comment: It might be the case of using polyfill for URL and URLSearchParams in the main process, with that polyfill not playing nicely with axios. What happens if you replace `.get(url)` with `.get(url.toString(), ...)`?

Comment: @JohnYepthomi Added output of console.log(url).

Comment: @raina77ow Then the error message changes to "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: unable to verify the first certificate", which also doesn't happen on the renderer process, but at least implies that axios accepted the URL. Why would there be polyfills for URL on the main process side?

Comment: Because the main process is running in a separate (node) env, which is different from the ones used by renderers ([docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model)). Node implementation of URL changed significantly in 10.x version, but remains stable since then.

Comment: Another possible cause of error is this: "Note: In Web Browsers, the WHATWG URL class is a global that is always available. In Node.js, however, the URL class must be accessed via require('url').URL.". That might impact axios' type check when evaluating its param.

Comment: @raina77ow Makes sense. So it looks like the solution is to not use URL on the main process side. If you can summarize your findings I'll accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between `URL` implementation in Chromium ([used by renderer processes](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#the-renderer-process)) and Node ([used by the main process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#the-main-process)) environments. In particular, WHATWG-compliant URL class is global (and always available) in the supporting browsers, yet became available globally only since Node 10.x; before that, it had to be only accessed through `require('url').URL` import.

It seems that this difference doesn't play well with `axios` type checks on its `url` parameter, causing `ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE` error. One way around it is avoiding passing `URL` completely, transforming it into string instead:

```
const url = new URL('https://www.devel.server/employee-contract-summary');
url.search = new URLSearchParams({ employeeId });
const urlString = url.toString(); // supported by URL class
axios.get(urlString).then(/* ... */)
```

Another approach worth checking is ensuring the code in the main process supplies axios with correct adapter, which might also eliminate the issue (as adapter should be responsible for bridging gaps like this).